# App crashes when 2 intents are declared inside same onClickListener

Tags: android, eclipse

Iam doing an IQtest app.I need to send 2 datas from one activity to 2 different activities.But when when I send them through single onClickListener the app crashes.Am I doing something wrong here?Or can I send the data without button click?

This is AgeCalculation.java

```
package com.example.iqtest;
public class AgeCalculation extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_age_calculation);
    mDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edDate);
    age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edAge);
    calage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalculateAge);
    go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    category=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.category);
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    Year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    Month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    Day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    mDate.setOnTouchListener(this);


    calage.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent(AgeCalculation.this,ResultActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("ti",timetotake);
            startActivity(i);
            Calendar now=  Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar.set(Year, Month, Day);

            int years = now.get(Calendar.YEAR) - calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int months = now.get(Calendar.MONTH) - calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int days = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            if (days < 0){
                months --;
                days +=now.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            }
            if (months < 0){
                years --;
                months +=12;
            }
            String yearsold = years+" YEARS "+months+ " MONTHS "+days+" DAYS"+" "+"OLD";
            age.setText(yearsold);
            if(years>=0 && years<=10)
            {
                opt=0;
            }else if(years>=11 && years<=15)
            {
                opt=1;
            }else if(years>=16 && years<=30)
            {
                opt=2;
            }
            else if(years>=31 && years<=50)
            {
                opt=3;
            }else if(years>=51 && years<=120)
            {
                opt=4;
            }else
            {
                opt=5;
            }
            switch (opt) {
            case 0:
                start=0;
                temp=" KIDS";
                timetotake=480;
                break;
            case 1:
                start=20;
                temp=" CHILDREN";
                timetotake=480;
                break;
            case 2:
                start=40;
                temp="TEENAGERS";
                timetotake=540;
                break;
            case 3:
                start=60;
                temp="ADULTS";
                timetotake=540;
                break;
            case 4:
                start=80;
                temp="ELDERS";
                timetotake=600;
                break;
            case 5:
                temp="ALIENS!!";
                break;
            default:
                temp="ALIENS!!";
                break;
            }
            category.setText(temp);
            go.setText("GO"+" "+"TO"+" "+temp+" "+"IQTEST");
            }
    });

    go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttongo);
    go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()        
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent intent = new  /*Here Iam using two intents to send data to two different activities QuizActivity and result activity*/Intent(AgeCalculation.this,QuizActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("start", start);
            startActivity(intent);
            Intent i = new Intent(AgeCalculation.this,ResultActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("ti",timetotake);
            startActivity(i);
        }


}); 
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    switch (id) {

        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(
                this, DateSetListener, Year, Month, Day);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener DateSetListener =
    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
    {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        Year = year;
        Month = monthOfYear;
        Day = dayOfMonth;
        String sdate = lp(Day + "", "0", 2)+ " " + montharray[Month] + " " + Year;
        mDate.setText(sdate);

    }

};

 private  String lp(String sc, String sp, int len) {
        String sr = sc;
        for (int i = sr.length(); i < len; i++) {
            sr = sp + sr;
        }
        return new String(sr);
    }

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
    return false;
}
}
```

This is QuizActivity.java

```
package com.example.iqtest;
public class QuizActivity extends Activity {
List<Question> quesList;
int score,qid,temp;
int secs;
Question currentQ;
TextView txtQuestion;
RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc,rdd,rde;
Button butNext,agecal;
private Button pause;
private TextView timerValue;
private long startTime = 0L;
private Handler customHandler = new Handler();
long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
long updatedTime = 0L;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
    timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);

     pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pause);
     pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {
            timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
             customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
              // or View.INVISIBLE depending on what you want to do
            pause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
           Intent i = new Intent(QuizActivity.this,Timeplease.class);
           startActivity(i); 
           finish();
         }
     });

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    qid=b.getInt("start");
    temp=qid;
    agecal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttoncalage);
    agecal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()        
    {
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(QuizActivity.this,AgeCalculation.class);
            startActivity(i); 
            finish();
        }

}); 
    DbHelper db=new DbHelper(this);
    quesList=db.getAllQuestions();
    currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
    txtQuestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    rda=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    rdb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rdc=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    rdd=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio3);
    rde=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio4);
    butNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    setQuestionView();
    butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RadioGroup grp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            RadioButton answer=(RadioButton)findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            if(currentQ.getanswer().equals(answer.getText()))
            {
                score++;
            }
            if(qid<(temp+20)){                  
                currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
                setQuestionView();
            }else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("score", score);
                b.putInt("time",secs);
                //Your score
                intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
}
private void setQuestionView()
{
    txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getquestion());
    rda.setText(currentQ.getopta());
    rdb.setText(currentQ.getoptb());
    rdc.setText(currentQ.getoptc());
    rdd.setText(currentQ.getoptd());
    rde.setText(currentQ.getopte());
    qid++;
}
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
int mins = secs / 60;
secs = secs % 60;
int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":" + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"+ String.format("%03d", milliseconds));customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
}
};

}
```

This is ResultActivity.java

```
package com.example.iqtest;
public class ResultActivity extends Activity {
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
        //get rating bar object

        //get text view
        TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textResult);
        //get score
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        int score= b.getInt("score");
        int timetaken= b.getInt("time");
        Bundle a = getIntent().getExtras();
        int timetobetaken= a.getInt("ti");
        int iqscore=score*160/20*timetobetaken/timetaken;
        //display score
       t.setText("YOUR SCORE IS"+ " "+ iqscore);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.result, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is Timeplease.java

```
package com.example.iqtest;
public class Timeplease extends Activity {
Button back;
Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context=this;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timeplease);
    addListenerOnButton();
}
public void addListenerOnButton()
{
    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonback);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()      
    {
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(context,QuizActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }

}); 
}
}
```

Comment: Use an object to update your values.

Comment: Where is your error ?

Comment: The error is when I use 2 intents inside go button in AgeCalculation.java

Answer (score 0):

After this line of code getting executed,

```
Intent i = new Intent(AgeCalculation.this,ResultActivity.class);
i.putExtra("ti",timetotake);
startActivity(i);
```

ResultActivity gets rendered. Other lines of code within your AgeCalculation is not executed. So, the values you are expecting in ResultActivity class will be null.

This could be the reason for crash.

Also, check the logcat which would tell you the line of code that led to crash.

Comment: exactly..I know that, but how in other way i could send data to another activity?

Comment: @user3167936, Save the data in Shared preferences and retrive it when needed. This is the simplest option

Answer (score 0):

In your `AgeCalculation` activity you are passing the values in the `Intent` only So you are suppose to get the values of  using `Intent intent = getIntent();` only. You can not get the values from your `Bundle` as you have not added the values in your Bundle.

And to get the values from your `Bundle` you can get it in from the bundle using `Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();`.

Try out as below:

```
  Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
   if(b.containsKey("score") || b.containsKey("time"))
  {
    int score= b.getInt("score");
    int timetaken= b.getInt("time");
   }

     Intent intent = getIntent();
     int timetobetaken=intent.getIntExtra("ti",0);
```

**In your `AgeCalculation` class you are simultaously starting the two activities on your go button click which might be causing the issue as you are passing the results to both the activities.**

Also in your `QuizActivity` class get the value from intent not from the Bundle as below:

```
  Intent b = getIntent(); 
  qid=b.getIntExtra("start",0);
```

**EDITED:**

Make your `timetotake` variable as `public static` in your `AgeCalculation` activity as

```
 public static int timetotake;
```

And access it in your `ResultActivity` as below:

```
 int timetobetaken= AgeCalculation.timetotake;
```

Comment: but in AgeCalculation activity can I declare 2 intents inside same button click(onClickListener) or is there any other way of sending data?

Comment: No, start the activities based on some conditions. You can not start two activities simultaoniously at the same time.

Comment: yeah exactly you told the problem Sir,but how in other way I could send the data "timetotake" from AgeCalculation class to ResultActivity class.

Comment: Either you can define some condition for the activities to start or you can store the value of `timetotake` into some global static constant and can access it from global variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir,it works.I thought we need to use intent only to access data of one activity by another activity.Hats off to you for helping new bees with your precious time.

Comment: @user3167936 You're always Welcome bro. :) Please Vote the answer if it helped you.

Comment: also there is a minor problem .I have defined another activity called Timeplease activity in which when the user clicks pause button it appears so that user doesn't get to see the questions,but when the user returns to the Question activity the timer resets.

Comment: @user3167936  Its because you are starting the `QuizActivity` again. Just do not finish your `QuizActivity` on the `pause` button click. So it will automatically pause the activity and start the `TimePlease` activity. And in your `TimePlease` activity's  `back` button click simply write `finish()` no need to start `QuizActivity` again.

Comment: thanks bro..It helped a lot.but since aim a beginner i can't vote.but honestly +100 for you from my side for help and support :)

Comment: Alright whenever you get enough reputations to vote then you can vote.  Thanks

Comment: bro..sorry for disturbing but my timer doesn't start when I return back to QuizActivity class.